# XML to CSV Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I have the following XML document:

```
<projects>
  <project>
   <name>Shockwave</name> 
   <language>Ruby</language> 
   <owner>Brian May</owner> 
   <state>New</state> 
   <startDate>31/10/2008 0:00:00</startDate> 
  </project>
  <project>
   <name>Other</name> 
   <language>Erlang</language> 
   <owner>Takashi Miike</owner> 
   <state> Canceled </state> 
   <startDate>07/11/2008 0:00:00</startDate> 
  </project>
...
```

And I'd like to get this from the transformation (XSLT) result:

```
Shockwave,Ruby,Brian May,New,31/10/2008 0:00:00
Other,Erlang,Takashi Miike,Cancelled,07/11/2008 0:00:00
```

Does anyone know the XSLT to achieve this? I'm using .net in case that matters.

Comment: .NET only matters if you are using the [XslTransform Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that only supports xslt 1.0. Is this a constraint? If so, it should be re-tagged to [xslt-1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-1.0/info).

Comment: A good answer is also given here to a similar question if you use Linux http://askubuntu.com/questions/174143/convert-xml-to-csv-shell-command-linee

Comment: There is the tool [xml2csv](https://github.com/fordfrog/xml2csv). Maybe, this is useful in your case, too?

Comment: xml2csv worked for me just fine.  I found that the documentation is broken, but took a moment to document the work-around which produced usable results for me, here:

https://github.com/fordfrog/xml2csv/issues/5#issuecomment-726542532

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Found an XML transform stylesheet [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160624174014/http://wenzlaff.de/xmltocsv.html) (wayback machine link, site itself is in german)

The stylesheet added here could be helpful:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>",    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position()  = last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>"<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Perhaps you want to remove the quotes inside the xsl:if tags so it doesn't put your values into quotes, depending on where you want to use the CSV file.

Comment: Be careful, if there is a comma in the original data, it is not escaped. You may want to add a test with contains() and an escape with translate().

Comment: I don't think this handles a double quote in the data. To escape a double-quote you must substitute it with two double-quotes.

Comment: Normally, one only needs to enclose a value in quotes if it contains any of the following: the delimiter ('`,`'), the quote ('`"`'), a newline (`&#xD;`). If quoting is required, any inner quotes must first be doubled ('`""`').

Comment: See the edit in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594364/xml-to-csv-using-xslt) if you need to select attributes as well.

Comment: Correct new line on unix is `&#10;` (\n). `&#xD;` is hexadecimal \r

Comment: It works but not exactly as required. It adds new line after every column. Also is there a way to add header (in the first row)? I translate as below to me. Shockwave,
      Ruby,
      Brian May,
      New,
      31/10/2008 0:00:00
Other,
      Erlang,
      Takashi Miike,
      Canceled,
      07/11/2008 0:00:00

Comment: The Link is dead

Comment: @BotMaster3000: thanks, replaced with a wayback machine link

Answer (score 58):

Here is a version with configurable parameters that you can set programmatically:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="projects/project" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="project">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove normalize-space() if you want keep white-space at it is --> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(), $quote)" />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like the mandatory quoting. At least when importing into, Excel, it takes care of the case where there is a $delim in the original data.

Comment: What we need to do if we want to also include the column names??

Comment: @omer There are a couple of ways to do this, depending on your XML. It's best if you ask a new question, because the comment section is not a good place to discuss things like this, and because in *this* thread it was not part of the question, so I won't edit the answer.

Answer (score 21):

This `xsl:stylesheet` can use a specified list of column headers and will ensure that the rows will be ordered correctly. It requires XSLT version 2.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <csv:columns>
        <column>name</column>
        <column>sublease</column>
        <column>addressBookID</column>
        <column>boundAmount</column>
        <column>rentalAmount</column>
        <column>rentalPeriod</column>
        <column>rentalBillingCycle</column>
        <column>tenureIncome</column>
        <column>tenureBalance</column>
        <column>totalIncome</column>
        <column>balance</column>
        <column>available</column>
    </csv:columns>

    <xsl:template match="/property-manager/properties">
        <!-- Output the CSV header -->
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    
        <!-- Output rows for each matched property -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="property"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property">
        <xsl:variable name="property" select="."/>
    
        <!-- Loop through the columns in order  -->
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">
            <!-- Extract the column name and value  -->
            <xsl:variable name="column" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="value" select="$property/*[name() = $column]"/>
        
            <!-- Quote the value if required -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($value, '&quot;')">
                    <xsl:variable name="x" select="replace($value, '&quot;',  '&quot;&quot;')"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $x, '&quot;')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($value, $delimiter)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $value, '&quot;')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        
            <!-- Add the delimiter unless we are the last expression -->
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    
        <!-- Add a newline at the end of the record -->
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is nice, but it would not work. `replace()` is an XPath 2.0 function. In XSLT 1.0 you'd have to use a recursive string replace template.

Comment: Worked for me with xsltproc/libxslt - it was good enough. Thanks for pointing out the requirements though.

Comment: @hd1, I'm still using this script in production so probably you are doing something wrong?

Comment: @hd1, perhaps if you told me exactly what is going wrong I'd be able to help?

Comment: @hd1, perhaps you can explain what your problem was and how you worked around it so other developers may benefit from your knowledge :)

Comment: Didn't use xsl at all, and decided to use SAX

Comment: If using Microsoft xml engine you can try msxsl script   `<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="scr">
    <![CDATA[ public string Replace(string stringToModify, string pattern, string replacement) { return stringToModify.Replace(pattern, replacement); } ]]>
  </msxsl:script>` Then use `<xsl:variable name="x" select="scr:Replace($value, '&quot;', '&quot;&quot;')"/>` and add these attributes to stylesheet node `<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"`

Answer (score 10):

This `CsvEscape` function is XSLT 1.0 and escapes column values `,`, `"`, and newlines like [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) or Excel. It makes use of the fact that you can recursively call XSLT templates:

- The template `EscapeQuotes` replaces all double quotes with 2 double quotes, recursively from the start of the string.
- The template `CsvEscape` checks if the text contains a comma or double quote, and if so surrounds the whole string with a pair of double quotes and calls `EscapeQuotes` for the string.

Example usage: `xsltproc xmltocsv.xslt file.xml > file.csv`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template name="EscapeQuotes">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($value,'&quot;')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($value,'&quot;')"/>
    <xsl:text>&quot;&quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="EscapeQuotes">
      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring-after($value,'&quot;')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="CsvEscape">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($value,',')">
      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="EscapeQuotes">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains($value,'&#xA;')">
      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="EscapeQuotes">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains($value,'&quot;')">
      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="EscapeQuotes">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>project,name,language,owner,state,startDate</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="projects/project">
      <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(name)"/></xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(language)"/></xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(owner)"/></xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(state)"/></xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(startDate)"/></xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that I have found to duplicate quotes with XSLT 1.0. Thanks!