# Convert XML file to CSV

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

After having converted a messed up XML using regex, I now need to change it yet again.
This source file

```
<product>
    <sku>SP00001</sku>
    <PID_OWNER_SellerID>StoreName</PID_OWNER_SellerID>
    <EANCode>8711983489813</EANCode>
    <DeliveryDays>2</DeliveryDays>
</product>
```

Has to become a CSV file, but like this:

```
sku        field                 value
SP00001    PID_OWNER_SellerID    StoreName
SP00001    EANCode               8711983489813
SP00001    DeliveryDays          2
```

I take it this is outside of regex' scope and has to be done with XSL?

Comment: Are you looking for code to resolve this? Or, an existing tool to convert xml to csv?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt

Comment: What programming language(s) do you want or have available?  It can be done via XSL, or you could use .NET or other languages to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some XSLT for you...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    >
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="headerRow" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//product" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="headerRow">
    <xsl:call-template name="rightpad">
      <xsl:with-param name="fieldvalue" select="'sku'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="fieldsize" select="number(11)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:call-template name="rightpad">
      <xsl:with-param name="fieldvalue" select="'field'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="fieldsize" select="number(22)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:text>value&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()[local-name(.) != 'sku']">

      <xsl:call-template name="rightpad">
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldvalue" select="../sku"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldsize" select="number(11)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="rightpad">
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldvalue" select="local-name(.)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldsize" select="number(22)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="rightpad">
    <xsl:param name="fieldvalue" select="string('')"/>
    <xsl:param name="fieldsize" select="0"/>

    <xsl:variable name="padded" 
                  select="concat($fieldvalue, '                   ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="result" 
                  select="substring($padded,1,$fieldsize)" />

    <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: there are better ways to form this XSLT.  But this is about the shortest.  I have a longer example that will automaticlly work if you add more elements.  But that stylesheet is about as long as the entire answer above.

Comment: I'm quite interested in that example, as I actually have about 84 different types of elements in the XML.

Comment: I'll post it on my blog this weekend (I don't really want to spam this answer.)  But the basic idea is I found a padding template to handler the fixed width and then I wrote a recursive template to query each product and loop the child elements with local-name(.)... Hard to describe what vary handy to use.

Comment: @skerit: Okay, I was too lazy to write up a blog post (yeah, I know... sad) anyway I replaced my answer above with the extended version of my template.  (Check the history if you want other details.)

Answer (score 6):

It's generally a bad idea to attempt to parse XML using regular expressions, as there's an infinite way to format an XML document that's structurally the same, and yet will bamboozle your regular expressions.

For files that aren't massive, definitely use XSL, remembering to specify 'text' as your output method.  Don't forget that you can invoke an XSL process programmatically if you must -- most languages let you do that.

For huge files, then consider writing a small program that uses a streaming API (e.g. SAX or one of the push-parser APIs).

Answer (score 1):

```
XPathDocumemt x = new XPathDocument("yourdoc.xml");    
XPathNavigator n = x.CreateNavigator();    
XPathNodeIterator i = n.Select("root/product");

List<string> fields = new List<string>() { "PID_OWNER_SellerID", "EANCode", "DeliveryDays" }

using (TextWriter w = File.CreateText("c:\\yourfile.csv"))
{
    w.WriteLine("sku, field, value");

    while (i.MoveNext())
    {
        foreach (string field in fields)
        {
            w.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", i.Current.SelectSingleNode("sku").value, field, i.Current.selectSingleNode(field).Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet will produce the output in the format specified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!--Spacing between column1 and column2 is 11 characters-->
  <xsl:variable name="col1-spaces" select="'           '" />
  <!--Spacing between column2 and column3 is 22 characters-->
  <xsl:variable name="col2-spaces" select="concat($col1-spaces, $col1-spaces)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!--Generate the heading row first, then apply templates-->
    <xsl:text>sku</xsl:text>
    <!--Add enough spaces after to align the next column-->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($col1-spaces, 3)"/>
    <xsl:text>field</xsl:text>
    <!--Add enough spaces after to align the next column-->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($col2-spaces, 5)"/>
    <xsl:text>value&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Do nothing with sku elements-->
  <xsl:template match="sku" />

  <!--For all elements that are children of product, except for sku, do this-->
  <xsl:template match="product/*[not(self::sku)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::sku"/>
        <!--Calculate how many spaces are needed using the length of the value of sku -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($col1-separator, string-length(preceding-sibling::sku))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
        <!--Calculate how many spaces are needed using the length of the name of the current element-->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($col2-separator, string-length(local-name()))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's what I need, though some field names are quite large.
When I try to use this in the "XSL Results" firefox plugin, it complains about an error in the stylesheet...

What do you use to apply this?

Comment: I thought about doing the padding this way... I should simply my extended example before I post it, thanks!