# convert xml document to comma delimited (CSV) file using xslt stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I need some assistance converting an xml document to a CSV file using an xslt stylesheet. I am trying to use the following xsl and I can't seem to get it right. I want my comma delimited file to include column headings, followed by the data. My biggest issues are removing the final comma after the last item and inserting a carriage return so each group of data appears on a separate line. I have been using XML Notepad.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="table">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*[1]" mode="header" />
              <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*" mode="row" />
        </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="header">
        <xsl:element name="tr">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="column" />
        </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
        <xsl:element name="tr">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="node" />
        </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="column">
        <xsl:element name="th">
              <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(.),'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm_','QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM ')" />
        </xsl:element>,
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="node">
        <xsl:element name="td">
              <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>,
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML to CSV using XSLT help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850788/xml-to-csv-using-xslt-help)

Comment: I checked the link given above to the other question and that does not help me. Thank You

Comment: Please, provide a sample XML document and also the exact result you want to get from it.

Comment: Also note that you are creating element in your result tree. I can not imagine how that could be interpreted as CSV.

Answer (score 5):

I use this to simple XSLT to convert XML to CSV; it assumes all child nodes of the root node are to be rows in the CSV, taking the element names of the first child of the root to be field names.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="*/*[1]/*">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
      <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*" mode="row"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="data" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="data">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(text(),',')">
        <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="doublequotes">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="doublequotes">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&quot;')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text,'&quot;'),'&quot;&quot;')" />
        <xsl:call-template name="doublequotes">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&quot;')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So this XML:

```
<csv>
  <row>
    <field1>foo</field1>
    <field2>ba"r</field2>
  </row>
  <row>
    <field1>foo,2</field1>
    <field2>bar,"2</field2>
  </row>
</csv>
```

Converts to:

```
field1,field2
foo,ba"r
"foo,2","bar,""2"
```

Not sure if this helps though, it depends how your XML is laid out.

Edit: Here's a more thorough transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="field" match="/*/*/*" use="name()" />
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="*/*/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('field',name())[1])]">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*" mode="row"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
    <xsl:variable name="row" select="*" />
    <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('field',name())[1])]">
      <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$row[name()=$name]" mode="data" />
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="data">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(text(),',')">
        <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="doublequotes">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="doublequotes">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&quot;')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text,'&quot;'),'&quot;&quot;')" />
        <xsl:call-template name="doublequotes">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&quot;')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This one will create a column in your CSV for all tag names that exist in all 'rows', and populate the appropriate column in each row.

Comment: You wrote: *it assumes all child nodes of the root node are to be rows in the CSV*. I think you're assuming more. Taking your example input document: you're assuming in your stylesheet that the fields in the first row are all the fields that can exist, and further that the fields of the individual rows are in the same order and that none are missing .

Comment: Of course, it's a fairly simple routine. I originally wrote it to convert a <table> tag in xhtml to CSV, which unless you've got colspan attributes works very well. XML's obviously a lot more flexible a format than CSV, so it's not going to convert well if it's not conforming to those assumptions. You can always verify that it is with an XSD first of course.

Comment: Thinking about it, it wasn't too hard to adapt the transform to do this properly; I've edited in a more thorough XSLT that doesn't make these assumptions; it still assumes your XML is only two levels deep however (below the root), and that each element one level deep is intended as a row. One limitation it does have is where a 'row' has identical tag names, ironically like a <table> tag. My original transform actually took the contents of the <th> tags as the column names rather than the node names; my first transform above was a more generalized version.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the "more thorough transform" of the xslt from @flynn1179 's answer.. but found that it was taking an extraordinary amount of time when the number of rows increased.  (this is using oracle dbms_xmlgen xslt transform )

I found that because I know what my 2 levels of data are called (ROWSET and ROW in this case) i was able to optimize the xslt and gain a significant performance increase.

My modified version (specifically aimed at oracle's dbms_xmlgen package) is below.  it also includes bits from other csv transforms I found around the internet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <!-- some variables for unprintable charcaters -->
<xsl:variable name="CRLF">  
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>  
</xsl:variable>  
<xsl:variable name="CR">  
  <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>  
</xsl:variable>  
<xsl:variable name="LF">  
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
</xsl:variable>  
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/ROWSET">
<xsl:for-each select="ROW[1]/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="$LF"/>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROW">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:value-of select="$LF"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROW/*">
  <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains( text(), ',' ) or   
                  contains( text(), $apos ) or  
                  contains( text(), $CRLF ) or  
                  contains( text(), $CR ) or  
                  contains( text(), $LF )">
    <!-- Field contains a comma, apostrophe and/or a linefeed, so quote --> 
    <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="doublequotes">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="doublequotes">
<xsl:param name="text" />
<xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&quot;')">
    <!-- recursive call -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text,'&quot;'),'&quot;&quot;')" />
    <xsl:call-template name="doublequotes">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&quot;')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```