# Converting xml to CSV using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

i am new to XSLT and have gone through some of the earlier thread on SO
[Thread i Followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt)

my requirements are similar and i need to convert XML to CSV, for e.g i have following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<impex>
<record>
<Employee/>
<UID>aa</UID>
<Name>HR Manager</Name>
<Groups/>
<Password>123456</Password>
</record>
<record>
<Employee/>
<UID>bb</UID>
<Name>HR Executive</Name>
<Groups/>
<Password>123456</Password>
</record>
</impex>
```

and i need to convert this XML to following csv output

```
INSERT_UPDATE Employee;UID[unique=true];name;groups(uid);password
;"aa";"HR Manager";;"123456"
 ;"bb";"HR Executive";;"123456"
```

where i have to manage csv headers dynamically (based on xml elements)

additonaly i have also to take care if some of the values are missing i can provide them 
e.g
 is missing or its empty in such case i need to provide some default value to the generated csv as this csv will be the final output which will be imported to the system

any starting help by which i can move ahead will be much appreciated

Comment: i am not familiar about xslt so i am struck how to create header as what i have saw so far is no header only the values

Comment: I would recommend that you start reading the W3CSchools XSLT tutorials. They are very good, and you will probably learn anough to solve your problem within an hour http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt

Comment: sure will do that..but any help will also be appreciated, i know i am asking much but this is something blocking my work :)

Comment: Why are you confusing your readers? I don't see anything in common between the provided XML document and the wanted result!

Comment: That XML structure looks like it can only have one record; is that true? If not, how would it contain more than one record?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: My mistake i corrected it,thanks for pointer.

Comment: @ Flynn1179: i have edited xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most beautiful, but it works

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/impex">
    <xsl:text>INSERT_UPDATE </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="record[1]/*" mode="header"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="record" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*" mode="header" >
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>;</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" >
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>;</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Per for this..though i also have to learn xslt myself and i am doing that but it can help me to get started a bit