# Convert XML to CSV using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, csv

Convert the XML into CSV using XSLT transformation

```
<start>
<article>
<key>key1</key>

<definition type="m">
<![CDATA[abcdefghijk]]>
</definition>
</article>

<article>
<key>key2</key>

<definition type="m">
<![CDATA[bcdefghijkl]]>
</definition>
</article>
</start>
```

csv will look like

```
key1,abcdefghijk
key2,bcdefghijkl
```

I'v learn w3c school xslt tutorial,but can't get practice.
Can someone write XSLT code for transformation?

Comment: I think this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the wanted result with a single template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="start/article">
        <xsl:if test="position()>1">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
            concat(key,'; ',definition))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//article/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="key">
    <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(concat(., ';'))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="definition">
    <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```