# XML to CSV Applying XSLT (formatting issue, logic error)

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT and XML. I have been going through tutorials and stackoverflow examples and learning a lot of new things.

Currently I am trying to apply XSLT on a XML file to transform it into CSV. What I am trying to achieve is that, I have some information in the XML file, which I would like to extract. The CSV file will have some information by default, which I am passing in the XSLT.

**Also I have used basic XSLT syntax that I learnt quickly and I am sure this is the worst way to do it. I would appreciate all the help, if anyone can guide me how to make this solution better.**

The issues I am having are as follows:

1. The information is not getting formatted properly, its getting printed on a new line, which I don't want unless I specify for a new line. Also if I don't indent the XSLT file then the information can be kept on single like but the code looks a mess, I am sure there is some easy way to do this.
2. Every person will have some licenses, which I want to read inside the for-each loop, but I am confused how to do that. As if the person doesn't have some licenses then by default I want it to be blank. Currently in this example I am using 5 states.

This is the xml file I am using to test.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<People>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
        </license>
    </licenses>
</Person>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
        </license>
    </licenses>
</Person>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <first-name>Xmen</first-name>
    <last-name>Bat</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">AK</state>
        </license>
        <license>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">CA</state>
        </license>
        <license>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
        </license>
        <license>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
        </license>
        <license>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
        </license>
    </licenses>
</Person>
</People>
```

The XSLT that I have written is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/People">First Name,Last Name,AK,CA,IL,NY,TX,default value1,required-tag1,required-tag2,default value2,default value3
    <xsl:for-each select="Person">
        <xsl:value-of select="first-name"/>, <xsl:value-of select="last-name"/>,<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="licenses/license/state='AK'">
      <xsl:value-of select="licenses/license/state"/>,
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>NA,
    </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose><xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="licenses/license/state='CA'">
      <xsl:value-of select="licenses/license/state"/>,
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>NA,
    </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose><xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="licenses/license/state='IL'">
      <xsl:value-of select="licenses/license/state"/>,
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>NA,
    </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose><xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="licenses/license/state='NY'">
      <xsl:value-of select="licenses/license/state"/>,
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>NA,
    </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose><xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="licenses/license/state='TX'">
      <xsl:value-of select="licenses/license/state"/>,
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>NA,
    </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>DEFAULT VALUE1,<xsl:value-of select="required-tag1"/>,<xsl:value-of select="required-tag2"/>,DEFAULT VALUE2,DEFAULT VALUE3<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried using a for-each loop within the for-each loop for licenses but that executed 5 times for all licenses, how do I execute the condition to test for license-state 5 time and keep the format proper as per default.

This is how I want to output to be:

```
First Name,Last Name,AK,CA,IL,NY,TX,default value1,required-tag1,required-tag2,default value2,default value3
Mike, Hewitt,NA,NA,IL,NA,NA,DEFAULT VALUE1,some-information,some-information,DEFAULT VALUE2,DEFAULT VALUE3
John, Jhonny,NA,NA,NA,NY,NA,DEFAULT VALUE1,some-information,some-information,DEFAULT VALUE2,DEFAULT VALUE3
Xmen, Bat,AK,CA,IL,NY,TX,DEFAULT VALUE1,some-information,some-information,DEFAULT VALUE2,DEFAULT VALUE3
```

**I am using XSLT version 1.0.**

Thank you, for helping.

Comment: For reference, a similar question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt You might find a few useful ideas there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the issue with new lines, consider how you are currently writing `NA` as an example

```
<xsl:otherwise>NA,
</xsl:otherwise>
```

Now, if you had just this...

```
<xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

Then XSLT would not output a new line at all. There is a text node under `xsl:otherwise` but it is a whitespace only node, so it is ignored. But as soon as you add normal text to it, like `NA` then XSLT considers all the text important, and outputs it including the new-line. It does not normalize any spaces.

The solution is to wrap all such text in `xsl:text`

```
<xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:text>NA</xsl:text>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

As for your logic issue, you are currently doing this to check for a state

```
<xsl:when test="licenses/license/state='IL'">
  <xsl:value-of select="licenses/license/state"/>,
</xsl:when>
```

But there is a subtle difference between the use of `licenses/license/state` in each statement. In the `xsl:when` you are asking "Is there a licence with this state", but in your `xsl:value-of` it will get the first state in the list!

Now, you could write this

```
<xsl:when test="licenses/license/state='IL'">
  <xsl:value-of select="licenses/license[state='IL']/state"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
```

But this is rather superfluous. Better to simplify it to this

```
<xsl:when test="licenses/license/state='IL'">
  <xsl:text>IL,</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
```

It is also worth mentioning you clearly have a lot of repetitive code, so you could remove some of this by using a named template.

Try this XSLT as an example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/People">
  <xsl:text>First Name,Last Name,AK,CA,IL,NY,TX,default value1,required-tag1,required-tag2,default value2,default value3</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Person">
        <xsl:value-of select="first-name"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="last-name"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="state">
          <xsl:with-param name="stateCode" select="'AK'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="state">
          <xsl:with-param name="stateCode" select="'CA'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
       <xsl:call-template name="state">
          <xsl:with-param name="stateCode" select="'IL'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="state">
          <xsl:with-param name="stateCode" select="'NY'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="state">
          <xsl:with-param name="stateCode" select="'TX'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>DEFAULT VALUE1,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="required-tag1"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="required-tag2"/>
        <xsl:text>,DEFAULT VALUE2,DEFAULT VALUE3</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="state">
  <xsl:param name="stateCode" />
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="licenses/license[state=$stateCode]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$stateCode"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>NA</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is still quite repetitive, with the repeated uses of `xsl:call-template`. if you did just want only 5 fixed states, you could put the states in an external XML document, and loop over that, as an example. That would be another question though.....

Comment: Thank you very much for such a simple and easy to understand descriptive answer. I have just learnt a lot of things in this solution.