# Retrieving content of XML documents regarding a specific tag

Tags: xml, xslt

First sorry for probably inexact title!

Retrieving or extracting content of an XML document is a frequent question that has been answered in other posts in SO.

For specific requirements of the desired algorithm, I should prepare the input in a table-like format in which it is not possible to have cells with more than one data item. Simply, for doc as follows (this is a fragment of complete doc):

```
<Articles>
<article>
<author>Frank Manola</author>
<title>title1</title>
<journal>GTE</journal>
<month>December</month>
<year>1991</year>
</article>

<article>
<author>Frank Manola</author>
<author>Sandra Heiler</author>
<title>title2</title>
<journal>ASF</journal>
<month>August</month>
<year>1993</year>
</article>
</Articles>
```

the desired output is such as follows:

```
Frank Manola, title1, GTE, December, 1991

Frank Manola, title2, ASF, August, 1993

Sandra Heiler, title2, ASF, August, 1993
```

In fact, for those records that have more than one authors (author tag) (there are instances with 4 or more ones), each one should be retrieved  in a separate line.

How to do that using XSLT?

Thanks,

Comment: Its actually a simple problem - have you tried anything yourself before posting a question that you could show us?

Comment: @Zyga, Unfortunately I don't have  enough knowledge of XSLT; however my another question of such kind has been answered in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032853/extracting-textual-content-from-xml-documents-using-xslt)

Comment: you will not learn if you are provided full solution every time. You should start with various XSLT tutorials and take it from there. I will actually provide you an answer this time though.

Comment: @Zyga, Thanks for kind advice and your coming answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSLT below should do what you want:

```
 <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Articles">
        <xsl:for-each select="article/author">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>, <xsl:value-of select="../title" />, <xsl:value-of select="../journal" />, <xsl:value-of select="../year" /><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```