# How to convert Schema XML to CSV using XSLT

Tags: mysql, xml, csv, xslt

The belwo is the xml from soapUI, I am facing diffulty to covnert this XML to CSV with the expected output bleow, I have tried multiple xsl but no  hope. looking for xsl for this scenario.

```
   <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <s:Body>
          <ReadResponse xmlns="http://abcde">
             <ReadResult xmlns:a="http://abcde" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:Failures xmlns:b="http://abcde"/>
                <a:GeneralErrorMessage i:nil="true"/>
                <a:Successes xmlns:b="http://abcde">
                   <b:OpenSuiteStatus i:type="c:QueryStatus" xmlns:c="http://abcde">
                      <b:Code i:nil="true"/>
                      <b:ErrorMessage i:nil="true"/>
                      <b:SourceIndex>0</b:SourceIndex>
                      <c:Dto xmlns:d="http://abcde">
                         <d:ColumnNames xmlns:e="http://abcde/Arrays">
                            <e:string>code</e:string>
                            <e:string>period_number</e:string>
                            <e:string>period_start</e:string>
                            <e:string>period_finish</e:string>
                         </d:ColumnNames>
                         <d:ColumnTypes xmlns:e="http://abcde/Arrays">
                            <e:string>string</e:string>
                            <e:string>int</e:string>
                            <e:string>dateTime</e:string>
                            <e:string>dateTime</e:string>
                         </d:ColumnTypes>
                         <d:ParsedSqlQuery>Select * from Table</d:ParsedSqlQuery>
                         <d:QueryResults xmlns:e="http://abcde/Arrays">
                            <e:ArrayOfanyType>
                               <e:anyType i:type="f:string" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">ABC</e:anyType>
                               <e:anyType i:type="f:int" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1</e:anyType>
                               <e:anyType i:type="f:dateTime" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2012-12-30T00:00:00</e:anyType>
                               <e:anyType i:type="f:dateTime" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2013-01-06T00:00:00</e:anyType>
                            </e:ArrayOfanyType>
                            <e:ArrayOfanyType>
                               <e:anyType i:type="f:string" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">DEF</e:anyType>
                               <e:anyType i:type="f:int" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2</e:anyType>
                               <e:anyType i:type="f:dateTime" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2013-01-06T00:00:00</e:anyType>
                               <e:anyType i:type="f:dateTime" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2013-01-13T00:00:00</e:anyType>
                            </e:ArrayOfanyType>               

                            </e:ArrayOfanyType>
                         </d:QueryResults>
                         <d:SqlQuery>Select * from Table</d:SqlQuery>
                      </c:Dto>
                   </b:OpenSuiteStatus>
                </a:Successes>
                <a:Warnings xmlns:b="http://abcde"/>
             </ReadResult>
          </ReadResponse>
       </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

### Expected OUtput:

ABC,1,2013-01-06T00:00:00,2013-01-06T00:00:00

DEF,2,2013-01-06T00:00:00,2013-01-06T00:00:00

### Deployed XSL: I have tried below but result is not as expected

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />

  <xsl:template match="/QueryResults">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ArrayOfanyType" />  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ArrayOfanyType">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />  
    <xsl:if test="not(last())">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />  
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ArrayOfanyType/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="not(last())">
      <xsl:value-of select="','" />  
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
                       ABC
                       1
                       2017-12-24T00:00:00
                       2017-12-31T00:00:00


                       DEF
                       2
                       2017-12-31T00:00:00
                       2018-01-07T00:00:00


                 Select * from Table
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt

Comment: Do you have a specific question or difficulty? Or are you just looking for someone to do your work for you? --- BTW, if that's really what your input looks like, you won't be able to do anything with it, because it's not a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML to CSV Using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt)

Comment: I have updated my question please clarify

Comment: "*I have tried multiple xsl but no hope*" Post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to understand that a node in a namespace cannot be selected by its local name without a prefix. You must declare the same namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix in your `select` and `match` expressions.

Next, the root element of your XML is `s:Envelope` - so a template matching `/QueryResults` will never be applied.

Now, the specified result can be achieved quite simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:e="http://abcde/Arrays">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//e:ArrayOfanyType">
        <xsl:for-each select="e:anyType">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

For better performance, replace the `//` part with the full path to `e:ArrayOfanyType`. But for this, you will need to add namespace declarations for all the namespaces used by the elements in that path.

Comment: Thanks michael. it is quiet infromative and learining.. especailly got ot know about declaring namespaces which is more important.... It worked with declaring all the namespaces  and with full path in //e:ArrayOfanyType. :-)

Comment: Hi Michael, I am facing “Output character not available in this encoding (decimal 8211)” due to encoding = "ISO-8859-1". It is advisable to use UTF-8 instead of that. Please advise.

Comment: I don't know what your target application requires.

Comment: our target is hive. so I am using UTF-8 instead of ISO

Comment: I am afraid I know nothing about that. And it has nothing to do with your question here. If you can use UTF-8 encoding without problems, go ahead. If not, post a new question.

Comment: UTF-8 is working fine

Comment: Hi michael. with the above Stylesheet i am facing issue with the records having ',' in it. so it is splitting those records. i tried with escaping those ',' in data but still the results are same.

Comment: I guess you need to add quotes around the value?