# Converting XML to CSV (using XSLT)

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have the following XML code, and need to convert this to a .csv file. 
I don't need the whole xml file, but i have to select some xml tags.

```
<contract_Set>
<contract_period>
    <reference>111111</reference>
    <startperiod>2017-09-01</startperiod>
    <endperiod>2017-09-06</endperiod>
    <vehicle_Set>
      <vehicle>
        <vehicle_id>4444</vehicle_id>
        <make>Mercedes-Benz</make>
      </vehicle>
    </vehicle_Set>
    <invoice_Set>
      <invoice>
        <id>12345</id>
        <description>Some text</description>
      </invoice>
    </invoice_Set>
    <invoice_Set>
      <invoice>
        <id>12222</id>
        <description>More text</description>
      </invoice>
    </invoice_Set>
</contract_period>
<contract_period>
    <reference>222222</reference>
    <startperiod>2017-09-01</startperiod>
    <endperiod>2017-09-30</endperiod>
    <vehicle_Set>
      <vehicle>
        <vehicle_id>55555</vehicle_id>
        <make>Audi</make>
      </vehicle>
    </vehicle_Set>
    <invoice_Set>
      <invoice>
        <id>45678</id>
        <description>Audi text</description>
      </invoice>
    </invoice_Set>
</contract_period></contract_Set>
```

I need my output to be like:

```
Reference;Make;Invoice_Id;Invoice_Description
111111;Mercedes-Benz;12345;Some text
111111;Mercedes-Benz;12222;More text
222222;Audi;45678;Audi text
```

How can i do this with XSLT 1.0? I have searched for solutions in similar questions, but no success. I'm looking to select values of some tags, not all tags.

Comment: "*Can i do this with XSLT 1.0?*" Yes.

Comment: You can *literally* search for your question title and find two dozen working solutions. Pick one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML to CSV Using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt)

Comment: this i s aduplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt

Comment: I have been searching for an answer in existing questions..ofcourse. I did not find any solutions where it is possible to select the values of some xml tags, while ignoring others.

Comment: Regardless of what solution you do find, one important thing you need to think about- what happens if your Make/Description fields contain a semicolon?

Comment: Hi i have tried for your question but i am getting partial output its useful for you or not i dont know i am giving template   <xsl:template match="contract_Set">
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="* except startperiod except endperiod except //vehicle_id except //id" separator=";"/>;
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

Answer (score 2):

The following XSL will provide the desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:variable name="separator" select="'&#59;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>Reference;Make;Invoice_Id;Invoice_Description</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        <xsl:for-each select="//invoice_Set">
            <xsl:value-of select="../reference" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
            <xsl:value-of select="../vehicle_Set/vehicle/make" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
            <xsl:value-of select="invoice/id" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
            <xsl:value-of select="invoice/description" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
Reference;Make;Invoice_Id;Invoice_Description
111111;Mercedes-Benz;12345;Some text;
111111;Mercedes-Benz;12222;More text;
222222;Audi;45678;Audi text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Reference;Make;Invoice_Id;Invoice_Description</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="contract_Set"/>     
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="contract_period">
      <xsl:value-of select="reference"/>;<xsl:value-of select="vehicle_Set/vehicle/make"/>;<xsl:value-of select="invoice_Set/invoice/id"/>;<xsl:value-of select="invoice_Set/invoice/description"/>;
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm only getting two records in my output.     111111;Mercedes-Benz;12222;More text   is missing