# XML to CSV using XSLT for multiple records separated by space in single tag

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

We are trying to convert XML to CSV using XSLT. I tried this link [XML to CSV Using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt) and [Converting XML to CSV (using XSLT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151921/converting-xml-to-csv-using-xslt) .

- It is converting normal xml to csv but in my Case I am unable to get
  the desired output.
- In my case I have multiple records which are separated by space in a single tag as mentioned in below xml input.

**Eg:-** Project and Rating tag contains the multiple records separated by space.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" version="2.0" href = "csvconverted.xsl"?> 
<TestData>
<project>Project-1 Project-2 Project-3</project>
<rating>2 3 5</rating>
<date>21-12-2018 21-06-2020 21-12-20</date>
</TestData>
```

**XSL:-**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TestData" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TestData">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove normalize-space() if you want keep white-space at it is --> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(), $quote)" />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
project,rating,date
Project-1,2,21-12-2018
Project-2,3,21-06-2020
Project-3,5,21-12-20
```

**Actual Output using the above code:-**

```
"Project-1 Project-2 Project-3","2 3 5","21-12-2018 21-06-2020 21-12-20"
```

Will be grateful if you could guide me further.

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1.0? If so, which processor will you be using? You need a radically different approach that will tokenize the space-delmited strings into individual values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and attention. As I am new to this new technology so I am not limited to the version. My requirement is that when we open it in browser it should return the expected output as shown in my sample. I have seen your profile and looks you are expert of this technology :), I would request you to kindly guide me on this. Thank you

Comment: I am afraid I am confused by your reply. You want a CSV result. What does a browser have to do with it? Browsers display HTML, not CSV. And browsers are limited to XSLT 1.0, with no extensions. Please clarify your exact processing chain.

Comment: @michael.hor257k , I have sample xml which needs to be converted to csv using xslt. And when we open this converted xml (for eg in browser or notepad++) it should display the converted values in csv format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor with no support for extensions.

I will also assume that the structure of the input XML is known in advance and the only thing that varies is the number of values in the 3 space-delimited strings.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/TestData">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>project,rating,date&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
        <xsl:with-param name="project" select="project"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="rating" select="rating"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="date"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="project"/>
    <xsl:param name="rating"/>
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <!-- generate row -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($project, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($rating, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($date, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="contains($project, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="project" select="substring-after($project, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="rating" select="substring-after($rating, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="substring-after($date, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvhL

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The above solution worked for me. As i am new to this so it would be grateful if you can explain me its working.:)

Comment: It works by calling a recursive template that creates a row by extracting the first token  from each one of the 3 space-delimited strings, then calls itself with the remainders of the strings. -- P.S. None of this should be necessary if your data provider took full advantage of the XML format, where data is supposed to be structured into elements and attributes, not delimited strings. --- P.P.S. This could be much simpler if you could use a tokenizing function - either as an extension function, or as part of XSLT 2.0.