# convert multiple xml to csv in apache camel

Tags: csv, apache-camel

I want to convert multiple xml object to csv  object in apache camel. But I am just able to convert single object. With reference to below and attached code, I have tried some method sI have xml file like this

```
<company>
<employee>
    <empId>1</empId>
    <empName>peter</empName>
    <sal>56000</sal>
</employee>
<employee>
    <empId>2</empId>
    <empName>mary</empName>
    <sal>96000</sal>
</employee>
<employee>
    <empId>3</empId>
    <empName>alex</empName>
    <sal>96000</sal>
</employee>
```

and want to convert it to csv. But I only manage to convert one data But i have no clue how to change the whole set

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

//      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();         

    JaxbDataFormat xmlDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat();                        //1.  XML Data Format
    JAXBContext con = JAXBContext.newInstance(company.class);
    xmlDataFormat.setContext(con);

DataFormat  csv  = new BindyCsvDataFormat(employee.class);


    from("file:C:/inputFolder/.camel/xml?noop=true")
    .unmarshal(xmlDataFormat)
    .split(body(String.class).tokenize(","))

//Unmarshaled debug part 
    .process(new Processor(){
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            //print string //

            String myString = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            System.out.println("unmarshalled output" + myString);
            //print string//

            //print array //
        //  Message msg =exchange.getIn() ;
        //  ArrayList<Employee> list = msg.getBody(ArrayList.class);
                    //list.forEach(emp -> System.out.println(emp));
            //print array //
            ////        }}

        }})
//Unmarshaled debug part 


    .marshal(csv)
    .to("file:C:/outputFolder/csv").

    // Marshalled output 
    process(new Processor(){
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        //print string//
                        String myString = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                       System.out.println("marshalled output" + myString);
                      //print string//

                        //print array //
                        //Message msg =exchange.getIn() ;
                    //  ArrayList<Employee> list = msg.getBody(ArrayList.class);
                    //          list.forEach(emp -> System.out.println(emp));
                        //print array //
                    }})                  
    ;}


}
```

Comment: It seems I can make use of hashmap , but how can i set the value ?  key is empId but how about  the value ?

Comment: Why dont you just use XSLT to convert XML to CSV it will use the raw XML and convert to CSV without you having to do one row at a time. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt

Answer (score 0):

You have to check **what result you get after the unmarshal** with jaxb.

I assume you get only one `employee` because you treat this result as String and split it by comma `,`. If there is, as my assumption is, no comma at all, you get only one part from the splitter: the whole input.

If the result from jaxb is a **Java collection of `employee`s** you can simply tell Camel

```
.split(body())
```

and you get each individual `employee` from the splitter.

If you want to **re-collect them after conversion** to write a CSV file with all entries of the XML you must add an aggregation strategy to your splitter, [see here for an example](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc#split-aggregate-requestreply-sample). Camel will then re-aggregate the converted elements of the consumed XML file automatically.

Very nice isn't it?