# XML to csv using xslt fro a specific node type

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to find nodes of type asset and put them in CSV via xslt . Can someone help with xslt to trsform below xml.

```html
<AssetData >
     <AssetMapping>
        <Owner>0</Owner>
        <AssetList>
          <Asset >
            <Name>SBS</Name>
            <Type>RealEstate</Type>
            <Location>Newzealand</Location>           
          </Asset>
    <Asset >
            <Name>KMK</Name>
            <Type>Equity</Type>
            <Location>NYSE</Location>        
          </Asset>             
    </AssetList>
 </AssetMapping>
</AssetData>
```

and I want text output like

```
Name,Type,Location
SBS,RealEstate,Newzealand
KMK,Equity,NYSE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML to CSV Using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt)

Comment: No, I am looking for matching specific node.Already visited the answer before posting.

Comment: "Can someone help" is not a question. Please post your attempt and pinpoint your difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::Asset">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:if test="not(position()=last())"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="not(position()=last())"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT to hide particular Column based on Name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::Asset">
        <xsl:variable name="varName"><xsl:text>Name</xsl:text></xsl:variable><!--Mention the name of column to hide here -->
        <xsl:variable name="varColPos">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(*[name()=$varName]/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:if test="not(position()=number($varColPos))"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="not(position()=last()) and not(position()=number($varColPos))"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:if test="not(position()=number($varColPos))"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="not(position()=last()) and not(position()=number($varColPos))"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you please also let me know how to exclude complete column like Name from CSV?

Comment: @TRS, to exclude 'Name' column also addressed in my post, pls check.

Comment: Thanks , I see that you exclude column by position. Its possible that position of element may change.Is it possible to exclude by name of the node like you do when selecting node select="descendant::Asset"

Comment: @TRS, I have updated the scripts to 'exclude the column based on Name'...